# Постановка запятой перед "вроде"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужна ли запятая: такое не случается с обычными парнями(,) вроде меня

Answer (score 1):

***...такое не случается с обычными парнями,  вроде меня.***

**Обособление оборота факультативно.** Если оборот относится к слову с неопределенным значением, которое **не имеет** другого определения, то он обычно не обособляется (является несогласованным определением).

В приведенном примере **определение уже есть**, поэтому обороту можно придать **уточняющее** значение, но это тоже на усмотрение автора.

Поэтому выбор в этом случае удобно дополнительно **проверить по интонации.**

Примеры:

Они сразу стали старенькие. Будут гулять теперь под руку на бульваре, и у какого-нибудь парня **вроде меня** сожмётся при их виде сердце. [Василий Аксенов. **Звездный билет** // «Юность», 1961]

Когда взрослые люди, **вроде меня**, произносят такие слова, они на самом деле хотят сказать, что заметили что-то... [Татьяна Соломатина. (2011)]